# Can I replace values of bit field to text in creating Table

Tags: sql, replace, bit

I tried but can't use CASE WHEN in CREATE TABLE code to replace 1 and 0 with text. Can someone help me to solve it. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which database platform you are on, but in SL Server, this is possible using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  ID int 
  , name varchar(50)
  , YesNo bit
  , TrueFalse AS 
    (
      CASE WHEN YesNo = 1 Then 'True'
      ELSE 'False'
      END
    )      
);
```

See the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35d18/3

Comment: Ya, sorry, I'm using SQL Server. Thank so much about your answer. But we have to add 1 more field into that table? Is there any way that don't need add 1 more field like that?